# How to set CSS File in Vaadin Application dynamically?

Tags: css, vaadin

i am injecting the Main CSS file with

```
@CssImport("./styles/views/main/main-view.css")
```

Now i need to change during runtime or at startup the css. For example if the app start on a hostname named "XY" then it should not use the main css, instead it should load another css file.

I dont find a way how to change the css during runtime/startup. Is there way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of programmatically switching the used css file, the [documented approach by Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/docs/next/styling/advanced/runtime-theme-switching) is to use multiple theme variants within one css.

You can use either CSS class name, or attribute like "theme" value to separate set of CSS that is effective in your selectors.

```
.forest-theme {
  --lumo-primary-color: green;
  --lumo-primary-text-color: darkgreen;
  --brand-color: forestgreen;
}

.fire-theme {
  --lumo-primary-color: orange;
  --lumo-primary-text-color: darkorange;
  --brand-color: orangered;
}
```

Then just use something like:

```
  // Remove the currently applied theme (if any):
  UI.getCurrent().getElement().getClassList().remove("forest-theme");

  // Apply the new theme:
  UI.getCurrent().getElement().getClassList().add("fire-theme");
  currentTheme = newTheme;
```

Comment: Of course, if the different themes are really big or very many, it might be better to load them dynamically: https://vaadin.com/docs/next/styling/advanced/loading-styles-dynamically (Although with that approach you're limited to light-DOM CSS)